# Combining files in .tar file in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I have a problem with zipping files in .tar file in Linux, but the challange is that when we extract .tar file it shouldn't give us a folder containing files which are zipped . It should give just files which we zipped in .tar file. How to do that? thanks!

Comment: What command are you using for zipping/unzipping?

Comment: i use tar -cvwf filename.tar filenamesss

Comment: Also note that when you are talking about use of tar, it's more commonly referred as "tarring/untarring", not zipping/unzipping which is confusing (to me at least)

Answer (score 3):

See the `--strip-components` flag. (But I strongly suggest you don't do this, it is expected that a tarball will have a single top level directory inside it).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to use:

```
tar cvf <tarfile name> <filename1> <filename2> <filename3>
```

When you extract the files, they should extract into the current directory.